# Vaadin 23 ErrorHandler for Async exceptions

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I have some basic `ExceptionHandler` view:

```
@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class ExceptionHandler extends VerticalLayout implements HasErrorParameter<Exception> {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event, ErrorParameter<Exception> parameter) {

        logger.error("Error", parameter.getException());

        Label label = new Label(parameter.getException().getMessage());
        add(label);

        return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    }

}
```

which works fine when error occurs in synchronous calls.

But when I use `@Async` feature, like for example:

```
    ListenableFuture<DecisionMatrixPage> listenableFuture = container.queryDataAsync();
    var ui = UI.getCurrent();
    listenableFuture.addCallback(page -> {

        ui.access(() -> {
            //do something
        });

    }, err -> {
        logger.error("Error", err);
        throw new AsyncException("Async error", err);
    });
```

I may only log the error but unfortunately rethrowing of `AsyncException` is not catched by `ExceptionHandler` view. How to properly re-throw exception to be catched by `ExceptionHandler` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be quite aggressive to use the same handler async? The user might be somewhere in your app and unless the exception now prevents any further work, the user could just continue and check out the problem later. I'd rather handle the error dedicated for this case (e.g. show a notification).

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right. I'll implement async error handling dedicated for each separate case to notify the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View implementing `HasErrorParameter` is used only when exception occurs during navigation. For more general exception handler you need to setup `ErrorHandler` using `VaadinSession#setErrorHandler`. The right place to setup the error handler is usually in the session init listener.

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/session-and-ui-init-listener